# Android - Edittext getting focus after dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, focus, android-edittext

I am calling a Dialog in an OnClick function in the OnCreate. In that dialog the user of the app can add something to a external database.

Now my problem is that when the dialog is gone ( myDialog.dismiss() ) and it is returning to the actual activity, an EditText is getting focussed. My whole screen contains Spinners and TextViews, except for only 1 EditText.

The weird thing is that when the activity is first called, it stats on top of the activity (showing the first Spinner and not foucssing the EditText), but when the dialog is dismissed, EditText is focussed.

I've got `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in the manifest within the activity tags

And i have tryed to put `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the EditText in the XML too, but that didn't work.

Can anyone help me find what i'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will focus the first focusable View from the top so you can try set something else focusable :)

Comment: hey thanks, I actually just tryed that, but now the situation gets more complicated;). The first time the dialog is dismissed, it shows the activity about in the middle (with the EditText focussed). But the second time open and dismiss the dialog (exact same action as before) it's focussing the upper spinner by using `klant.requestFocus(); 
                klant.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`. Do you have a clue what can be the issue there?

Comment: Have you tried to set one of the TextViews over the EditText to focusable?

Comment: I've tryed to set the upper spinner as focus, but that only works the 2nd time, but i need it to work the first time. The TextViews are even lower than the EditText, so that wont work:p

Comment: Try to set android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and android:focusable="true" in the xml on the spinner then call requestFocus

Comment: Not much luck again.. :(

Comment: What if you remove focus from the editText manuel in code then it will focus the next View i think

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i solved it an other way. My app is a sort of fill in form, so i moved the only EditText on the first screen to the second screen (with multiple EditText's). So now it just stats the activity on top after using a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Android focus is somewhat random, you can't really control it. You could try to disable the textview and enable it again when the dialog is gone, but I would advice against it.

To be honest, just let Android do it's thing. We have tried to work against the focus logic in a really big app and gave up after a lot of tries and convinced the customer it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe there is a way to let the activity scroll to top when the dialog is dismissed? Or maybe is there a way to set the focus to a spinner?? Then the problem is solved too

Comment: Scrolling to the top is even worse for the user. And you cannot "set" focus, you can only request it. My experience with `requestFocus` is that it's ignored 90% of the time

Comment: Ye i couldnt get requestFocus to work either, so you dont know any other way around this issue?

Comment: We really spent a lot of energy on this issue. There's no way around the android focus. You can try to make labels focusable but that will destroy the app for blind people (not good) and people using keyboards (could care less)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem. Try:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
        }
    });




private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

This worked for everything except for a button in my dialog that has only an 
`onDismiss()` method. Adding `focusable=true` and `focusableInTouchMode=true` to a TextView above my EditText (as Jeppe Andersen mentioned) solved this issue. Hope this helps.